# If $f:A\to P(A)$, show that $Z_f := \{x \in A | x \notin f(x)\}$ is not in the Image of $f$

Tags: calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that for a function $f: A \to P(A)$, $Z_f := \{x \in A | x \notin f(x)\}$ is not in the Image of f?

It can be shown using Russel's Paradox, but i have really no clue on how to start. Is there any Idea, even without using Russel?

Comment: Not *using* Russell's paradox, but rather *parallel to* it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Z_f$ is in the image of $f$. Then $Z_f = f(a)$ for some $a \in A$. Use the definition of $Z_f$, and the assumption that $Z_f = f(a)$, to prove that neither $a \in Z_f$ nor $a \not \in Z_f$, which is a contradiction since it must be true that either $a \in Z_f$ or $a \not \in Z_f$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $Z_{f}\in\text{im }f$, so that some $a\in A$ exists with
$f\left(a\right)=Z_{f}$.

For $a$ there are two possibilities: $a\in Z_{f}$
or $a\notin Z_{f}$.

If $a\in Z_{f}$ then $a\notin f\left(a\right)=Z_{f}$ and a contradiction
is found.

If $a\notin Z_{f}$ then $a\in f\left(a\right)=Z_{f}$ and a contradiction
is found.